# Use Expo without their OTA

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to know if there is a way to use Expo SDK without publishing on their servers. To be honest, i want to use my own OTA server with Electrode and a react native app, but, Expo has many helpful native resources (fb ads, SecureStore, admob, push notitications, FileSystem, Asset, Payments and many  many more...).
I have read and apparently it is imposible (i guess) use Expo SDK Api without using Exp online services even detaching or ejecting (CRNA) the app.

I apreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the follow properties to `app.json`

- [`"updates": { enabled: false }`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration.html#enabledif-set-to-false-your-standalone-app):

  > If set to false, your standalone app will never download any code, and will only use code bundled locally on the device.
- [`"assetBundlePatterns": [<insert paths>]`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration.html#assetbundlepatternsan-array-of-file-glob-strings-which) (if you use any local assets):

  > An array of file glob strings which point to assets that will be bundled within your standalone app binary.

If you need to [detach](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach) (to add other native modules), you need to be on [Expo SDK v27](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v27-0-0-is-now-available-898bf1e5b0e4):

> ExpoKit projects on iOS and Android which were created with exp detach now support bundling your assets inside your native app archive so that your app can launch with no internet.

The Expo team is also planning to add the following features:

- [modularise the SDK to allow non-Expo projects to use the sdk](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/publish-expo-sdk-modules-for-use-in-vanilla-react-native-projects)
- [allow JS bundle and assets to be self-hosted](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/self-hosted-remote-js-bundle--assets).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But how can i generate the apk without uploading to expo servers like normal react native does. i tried detaching, generating gradle wrapper and generating a gradlew assenbleDebug or assembleRelease but it starts to compile until TransformExpoAssets and build failed

Comment: Sounds like a completely different issue. The build process is completely offline once you detached. Try creating a new detached project and see if you are able to build it.